# Is it possible to sync my Pyzor server with public Pyzor servers?

Tags: spam, spam-prevention, spamassassin

I am expecting my mail traffic to increase in the future and setting up a local Pyzor server as recommended in the docs. Is there a way to populate this database by syncing with the public Pyzor servers? What is the best way to populate this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's officially no way to do this. Frank Tobin had a plan to start a peering system in 2002, but it never got implemented.

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/pyzor/mailman/message/1449003/